# Cant have a new line inside a fraction in latex

Tags: mathtools

Is it possible in latex to have a new line inside a fraction.
I have this fraction and I want it to appear not in the same line.

I have this formula but the \ break line after Disponibilidad doesnt do any difference:

```
\[Disponibilidad\\=\frac{t_{func}}{t_{total}}=\frac{t_{total}-t_{act}-t_{rep}-t_{reinicio} }{t_{total}}=\frac{365\times24horas-4\times1horas-(250+250+250)1horas-\frac{5250\times5horas}{60}}{365\times24horas}=\frac{7568,5}{8760}=0,8639\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You are not using the appropriate environment for this, try e.g. `align`.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft{\text{Disponibilidad}}\\
&=\frac{t_\mathrm{func}}{t_\mathrm{total}}=\frac{t_\mathrm{total}-t_\mathrm{act}-t_\mathrm{rep}-t_\mathrm{reinicio}
}{t_\mathrm{total}}\\
&=\frac{365\times24\text{horas}-4\times1\text{horas}-(250+250+250)1\text{horas}-\frac{5250\times5\text{horas}}{60}}{365\times24\text{horas}}\\
&=\frac{7568,5}{8760}=0,8639
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I really just focus on the line breaks, in particular the one you indicated. There is still some considerable room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        & \text{Disponibilidad} \\
        & =\frac{t_{func}}{t_{total}} \\ 
        & =\frac{t_{total}-t_{act}-t_{rep}-t_{reinicio} }{t_{total}}  \\
        &=\frac{365\times24 \text{horas} - 4 \times 1 \text{horas}-(250+250+250)1 \text{horas}-\frac{5250\times5 \text{horas} }{60}}{365\times24 \text{horas}} \\
        & =\frac{7568,5}{8760}=0,8639
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've added `\text{}`around the horas, making it clearly visible as text and not variables. You should do the same with `t_`as `\mathrm` simply changes the font.

AFAIK: if you change the text for the document, `\text` gets updated as well, `\mathrm` does not (this needs to be confirmed as it is something I remember vaguely to have read a long time ago).

Answer (score 1):

To create a linebreak in the very long numerator term of the second-to-last `\frac` expression, use the `\splitdfrac{...}{...}` macro, which is provided by the `mathtools` package.

I would also switch from the unnumbered single-line equation environment to an `align*` environment. In addition, I'd typeset all variable names in upright roman letters rather than in math mode. And, I'd insert thinspace between the number of hours and `horas`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "variable name"

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vn{Disponibilidad}
&=\frac{t_{\vn{func}}}{t_{\vn{total}}}
 =\frac{t_{\vn{total}}-t_{\vn{act}}-t_{\vn{rep}}-t_{\vn{reinicio}} }%
      {t_{\vn{total}}}\\[1.5ex]
&=\frac{\left(\splitdfrac{365\times24\,\vn{horas}-4\times1\,\vn{horas}}%
    {-(250+250+250)1\,\vn{horas}-\frac{1}{60}(5250\times5\,\vn{horas})}%
    \right)}{365\times24\,\vn{horas}}\\
&=\frac{7568{,}5}{8760}=0{,}8639
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```